# Should you inject viewholders when implementing DI?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dependencies, code-injection, dagger-2

Im currenly implementing dependency injection using dagger2 in my project and I stumbled upon something, Im confused on what's the best apporach when dealing with viewholders in a recyclerview.

Normally, we create the viewholders like this:

```
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int pos) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
```

Now my question is, how can I inject the ViewHolder?
Should I even inject it or should I just leave it be?

Comment: This really is just a matter of opinion. I personally would not use Dagger for view creation and inflation, but only for the 'business logic' stuff

Comment: Agree with @DavidMedenjak. I prefer the approach of injecting Activities/Fragments and then building the object graph manually from there. (i.e. pass the stuff on the Adapter's constructor, and to the ViewHolders from there). Having said that, if you do want to inject it, probably the easiest way would be to create and `inject(ViewHolder)` method in your component, and have package-private fields with `@Inject` annotations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dagger 2 and other dependency injection frameworks help you to write single responsibility classes that are easier to test by managing the constructors for you. This is their main advantage.

In the specific code for the question (for a `RecyclerView.Adapter`) there is no extra profit to be gained by using Dagger 2 or dependency injection and it is fine to continue using the `new` keyword and the static factory to inflate the view:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int pos) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

In other words, you won't be testing the `ViewHolder` by swapping in real dependencies for mocks so there is no point in using Dagger 2 here.

If you wanted to increase readability you could consider using data binding where you would end up with something like this:

```
return new ViewHolder(ListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())));
```

Alternatively, if you had a very complex logic for producing the `ViewHolder` you could inject the `RecyclerView.Adapter` into your Activity. Then you could inject a `ViewHolderFactory` inside your Adapter and use that to create the view:

```
private final Context context;
private final ViewHolderFactory viewHolderFactory;

@Inject
MyAdapter(Context context, ViewHolderFactory viewHolderFactory) {
    this.context = context;
    this.viewHolderFactory = viewHolderFactory;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int pos) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return ViewHolderFactory.create(view);
}
```

It would then be possible to easily test against the `ViewHolderFactory` rather than against the heavyweight adapter.